# Error when running my ios sumilator : Exception '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I have just done some configs in Xcode and appdelegate.m for RNFirebase, RNFBSDK, and google Sign-In. After following al the steps I have an error when running my ios simulator with react-native run ios.

I have tried to tweak the AppDelegate.m, I deleted my build folders and recompiled

My AppDelegate.m file looks like this

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h>
#import <RNGoogleSignin/RNGoogleSignin.h>
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  // Firebase configurations
  [FIRApp configure];

  // Facebook SDK
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
}

// RNGoogleSignin.h -> https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/docs/ios-guide.md#modify-your-app-to-respond-to-the-url-scheme-optional
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(nonnull NSURL *)url options:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
  return [RNGoogleSignin application:application
                             openURL:url
                   sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                          annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
}

// FACEBOOK SDK
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                openURL:url
                                                      sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                             annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  if ([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options]) {
    return YES;
  }

  if ([RCTLinkingManager application:app openURL:url options:options]) {
    return YES;
  }

  return NO;
}

@end
```

this is the entire error popping on the simulator screen instead of the app launching:

```
Exception '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]' was thrown while invoking getImageForFont on target RNVectorIconsManager with params (
    Entypo,
    "\Uf241",
    30,
    4278190080,
    35
)
callstack: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f926fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011097eac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111ee0ddc _CFThrowFormattedException + 194
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111ffec31 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 321
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f8e3db +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 59
    5   madilist_app                        0x000000010d8339bf -[RNVectorIconsManager createAndSaveGlyphImage:withFont:withFilePath:withColor:] + 415
    6   madilist_app                        0x000000010d833d68 -[RNVectorIconsManager getImageForFont:withGlyph:withFontSize:withColor:callback:] + 360
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f994cc __invoking___ + 140
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f96a45 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 325
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f96e96 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
    10  madilist_app                        0x000000010d528fba -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 2810
    11  madilist_app                        0x000000010d5db096 _ZN8facebook5reactL11invokeInnerEP9RCTBridgeP13RCTModuleDatajRKN5folly7dynamicE + 790
    12  madilist_app                        0x000000010d5daba3 _ZZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEiENK3$_0clEv + 131
    13  madilist_app                        0x000000010d5dab19 ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke + 25
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011497accf _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011497bd02 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114982720 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 705
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114983261 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 398
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011498bfcb _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 645
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000114d5d611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
    20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000114d5d3fd start_wqthread + 13
)

RCTFatal
facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&)
facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const
invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_lane_serial_drain
_dispatch_lane_invoke
_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
_pthread_wqthread
start_wqthread
```

Comment: This is the key error: `NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]' `. Set an exception breakpoint to see where it's triggered.

Comment: I have two methods duplicated and I don't know how to combine them, each of them is required for the google sign in and facebook sdk. I have set a breakpoint in the appdelegate.m but I don't know how to use it in xcode

Comment: Same issue, only not using `react-native-firebase` but the plain `firebase-js-sdk`.